# Почему нет запятой в ССП?

Tags: синтаксис, пунктуация

Фраза из интернета. Почему нет запятой?

После фильма "И Бог создал женщину" она стала известной актрисой и с ней хотели работать многие режиссеры.

Уточняю вопрос. Правильно ли я понимаю, что постановка запятой меняет смысл фразы: если запятой нет, значит режиссеры хотели работать с ней вследствие выхода фильма, а если поставить запятую, то это будет означать, что режиссеры хотели работать с ней вследствие ее известности, обретенной после выхода фильма?

Comment: К уточнению. Тогда зачем нам (предложению) соединительный союз? Из-за него же весь сыр-бор.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что к обеим частям ССП относятся слова "после фильма". Что и отменяет запятую.

> Запятая в ССП не ставится, если соединенные союзами предложения имеют
>   общие второстепенный член, вводное слово, сравнительный оборот или
>   общее придаточное предложение.

Подробно см. [**§ 30.2**](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827516.html).

Comment: После фильма "И Бог создал женщину" она стала известной актрисой и(вследствие чего) с ней хотели работать многие режиссеры.



После фильма "И Бог создал женщину" она стала известной актрисой и с ней хотели работать многие режиссеры. Здесь два независимых события.Режиссеры хотели работать из-за фильма, а не из-за того,что она стала известной актрисой.  Два смысла,а пунктуация одинаковая.Как тогда различить предложения?

Comment: Не получаются "два независимых события" именно из-за общего второстепенного члена: и то и другое случилось "после фильма" (известность и желание работать с актрисой).

Comment: Известность человека и желание с ним работать не являются в логике обязательной причинно-следственной связью.Ведь желание работать могло возникнуть как из-за хорошо сыгранной роли(профессиональный интерес к актрисе),так и из-за её появившейся известности.Это разный смысл.Мне кажется,что трактовка здесь может быть разная.Вы не согласны?

Comment: Не согласна. *Известность человека и желание с ним работать* явились следствием выхода фильма на экран. Выход фильма ("после фильма") принёс славу актрисе, её игру оценили режиссёры и захотели работать с ней. "Причинно-следственную связь" организовал этот самый прокат  ("после фильма"), который не позволяет ССП делиться на два самостоятельных предложения.

Comment: Относительно выхода фильма события всегда зависимы,а относительно друг друга?

Comment: Относительно друг друга события выглядели бы так: "Фильм "И Бог создал женщину" сделал её известной актрисой, и с ней хотели работать многие режиссеры".

Comment: Понятно.Всё упирается в "так говорить нельзя",хотя так говорят в повседневной жизни.И если мы хотим передать на бумаге разговорную речь,которая является очень абстрактной,и контекст известен нашему собеседнику,то невозможность постановки  запятой очень ограничивает наши возможности по цитированию,например, да и русский язык уже не будет выглядеть"великим и могучим".Мне кажется,что уровень любого языка всё-таки раскрывается в абстрактности.